# Taking an app version off review in Google console

Tags: android, google-developers-console, rollout

Is there a way to remove an app version that is currently "In review" in Google Console? It's been in review for almost two days (usually it took a couple hours tops) and we have worked on new updates that we'd like to rollout.

Comment: No, you can not remove it. However, if you publish another update now it will supersede the current.

Comment: I don't think so. You can however roll out another apk and it will override the previous one. Also do look at Google Play Console -> Publishing Overview -> Changes in Review.

P.S : It also takes couple of hours for me but my last release last week took 7 days!!